# Find and Replace with Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, find-and-replace

Having a large list with icons to include in HTML

`icon-picons-abacus
icon-picons-add
icon-picons-airplay
icon-picons-alert`

HTML Code

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col"><em class="icon-picons-diamond"></em>
```

The word 'diamond should be replaced with the last word of the list (abacus, add, airplay, alert, and so on)

Tried it with find:

```
icon-picons-.*?
```

And several variations of replace, here only one:

```
\1<div class="col-sm-4 col"><em class="(*)"></em>
```

Always missing the part 'icon-picons-' and the place holder word (abacus, add, airplay, alert, and so on) appears at the end and not at the position after 'class'.
Getting search result:

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col"><em class="*"></em>abacus
```

Instaed of

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col"><em class="icon-picons-abacus"></em>
```

Thanks in advance, for your help,
Go

Comment: I am confused. What is `<div class="col-sm-4 col"><em class="icon-picons-diamond"></em>` supposed to turn into?

Answer (score 0):

With extended expression you capture with parens `()` and replace the "n"th capture with `\n`. Note that isn't newline but n should be a number.

However, if I understood the question correctly, you have numerous diamond and need to replace each one with a different icon? Each successive one in the list of icons? I would look into replacing with a python plugin.

Answer (score 0):

#### The word "diamond" should be replaced with the last word of the list (abacus, add, airplay, alert, and so on)

- Menu "Search" > "Replace" (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>)
- Set "Find what" to `icon-picons(.*)`
- Set "Replace with" to `<div class="col-sm-4 col"><em class="icon-picons\1"></em>`
- Enable "Regular expression"
- Click "Replace All"

  [image]

**Before**:

```
icon-picons-abacus
icon-picons-add
icon-picons-airplay
icon-picons-alert
```

**After**:

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col"><em class="icon-picons-abacus"></em>
<div class="col-sm-4 col"><em class="icon-picons-add"></em>
<div class="col-sm-4 col"><em class="icon-picons-airplay"></em>
<div class="col-sm-4 col"><em class="icon-picons-alert"></em>
```

---

#### Further reading

- [Notepad++: A guide to using regular expressions and extended search mode](http://markantoniou.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot David,

that's perfectly what I wanted.

Sorry, your post crossed with my last post

You're leaving me happy - Go

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot, Hank,

I want to clarify this:
1. I have a list with over 500 rows icons and I want to add HTML code to the icon names, here three examples:

```
icon-picons-abacus, icon-picons-add, icon-picons-airplay and so on...
```

2. I want to add this HTML Code before:

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col"><em class="
```

and this HTML code after the icon name

```
"></em>
```

3. The result for all 500 rows should look like:

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col"><em class="icon-picons-abacus"></em>
```

4. Instead of 'abacus' always the last word of 'icon-picon-'. Next would be 'add', then 'airplay', 'alert' and so on.

Hope I explained it well
;-)

Go

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please use the **Post Your Answer** button only for actual answers. You should [edit] your original post to add additional information.